# Details of file.exists() in Java?

Tags: java, file, java-io

I'm using the following code to check if a file exists and can be read in Java:

```
File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
if (!sourceFile.exists() || !sourceFile.canRead())
    throw new Exception("Source file is not accessible.");
```

However, the issue I want to resolve is determining more granular detail about *why* exists() may or may not return false.  For example, the location may be accessible, but the file does not exist.  Or, the location may be blocked by a firewall and the file does exist, just not accessible.

Is there a quick way to make the determination between:

- File location is not accessible (firewall, security, etc.)
- Location is accessible, but file d.n.e.
- File exists but read is not granted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `File` you cannot.

With `Path`, you can:

```
thePath.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess(thePath)
```

[javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html#checkAccess-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.AccessMode...-).

Comment: Looks like this class can provide the details I'm looking for.

Comment: try{
Path thePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(sourcePath);
thePath.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess(thePath, AccessMode.READ);
}          
catch (NoSuchFileException ex1)
{
throw new Exception("Source file does not exist.");
}
catch (FileSystemException ex2)
{           
// Example: The network path was not found.
throw new Exception("Source file is not accessible: " + ex2.getReason());           
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception("Unknown exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}

Comment: This is what I ended up with.  Feeds into my program's exception handler, but with more details.

Answer (score 0):

below the exists method and checkRead method code:

```
     public boolean exists() {
         SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
         if (security != null) {
             security.checkRead(path);
         }
         return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);
     }

     public void checkRead(FileDescriptor fd) {
         if (fd == null) {
             throw new NullPointerException("file descriptor can't be null");
         }
         checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("readFileDescriptor"));
     }
```

Exist method is performing the file check read.

please refer to the following link in order to grant read to a given file using the SecurityManager

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html)